# Using a custom defined variable in php header

Tags: php

I am building a log in system but when the user logs in i'm using the PHP header function and it doesn't work I get a 404 error saying

> The requested URL /account/_paw/sos/login/$url was not found on this server.

My code is as follows...

```
else {
$_SESSION['usr_bnmp_core_personal_identifier'] = $login;
header('Location: $url');
exit();
}
```

In my config.do.php i define my url as

```
//DEFINED URL WITHOUT TRAILING SLASH
$url = 'https://myaccount.mysitename.com';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's a quote issue. Change `header('Location: $url');` to `header("Location: $url");`.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, that was really simple, please add as an answer so i can give you the best answer response

Comment: I've added it as an answer with a bit of an explanation for future readers of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quote issue. The variable `$url` is not interpolated when in single quotes. Changing it to double quotes solves this problem.

Change `header('Location: $url');` to `header("Location: $url");`.